# How to combine two contents of same type and display in views

Tags: views

How to combine two contents of same type and display in views?

the following picture will clear my question.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that, [Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows). From the project's description:

> Sometimes when you use relationships in views you get a number of rows
>   with the same content in some of the fields. This results in a huge
>   table (grid, list, etc.) that affects the usability of your view. The
>   Views Merge Rows module provides a way to combine rows with the same
>   content in the specified fields.

Keep in mind that there is a pretty straightforward guide to configure the module in the project's page that includes very descriptive screenshots.